# Parsing whitespace before or-else with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am using the `Parsec` module in Haskell to parse files. One of the components of these files are colors. I have created a type for colors like this:

```
data Color = Yellow | Red | Blue | Green deriving (Show)
```

My initial attempt at parsing colors looks like this:

```
symbol :: String -> Parsec String () String
symbol s = spaces >> string s

colorP :: Parsec String () Color
colorP = 
   liftM mkColor $ symbol "Yellow" <|> symbol "Red" <|> symbol "Blue" <|> symbol "Green"
  where
   mkColor :: String -> Color
   mkColor "Yellow" = Yellow
   mkColor "Red" = Red
   mkColor "Blue" = Blue
   mkColor "Green" = Green
```

I created the `symbol` parser which basically eats as much whitespace as possible and then eats the given string `s`. However, this does not seem to work. I test this code with the following call:

```
parse colorP "" "        Red"
```

This gave me the following error:

```
unexpected "R"
expecting space or "Yellow"
```

However, I went looking on Hoogle for the documentation that goes with the `<|>` operator and there I found the following:

> This combinator implements choice. The parser p <|> q first applies p. If it succeeds, the value of p is returned. If p fails **without consuming any input,** parser q is tried.

So, I think the problem with the above example is that parser `p` (in this case `symbol "Yellow"`) already did consume some input, namely the blanks! So, I refactored my `colorP` like this:

```
colorP =
  liftM mkColor $ spaces >> (string "Yellow" <|> string "Red" <|> string "Blue" <|> string "Green")
 where
   -- mkColor same as before
```

which gives the result I want.

Now, I am wondering if there is no parser like the `symbol` parser that I wrote, but that puts back the input in case of a failure. Or is the second implementation of `colorP` the one that is most Haskell-ish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [try](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:try)

```
symbol s = try (spaces >> string s)
```

> The parser try p behaves like parser p, except that it pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs.